# Fullpage.js not scrolling to full height of the content

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js, slimscroll

I've implemented the [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) plugin but I'm having an issue when the section of the content is too long for the page.  As you can see from the following link:

http://ymorin007.webfactional.com/events/UFC174/ and going to the section Leaders from any device or desktop.

You will notice that the scroll bar ends before it has reach all the table content.

So how do I fix this issue so the scrollbar will see the full table content.

my fullpage() declaration:

```
$('#container-event-page').fullpage({
        verticalCentered: false,
        loopHorizontal: false,
        scrollOverflow: true,
        css3: true
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Fix it by removing the top padding from the body and applied it to the paddingTop option from the fullpage() function and it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had imported `scrolloverflow.js`?

```
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"</script>
<script src="jquery.easing.min.js"</script>

<!-- DO NOT FORGET this one -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="scrolloverflow.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fullpage.js"></script>
```